# Subbasis of a weak topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{(X_\alpha,\mathscr{T}_\alpha):\alpha\in\Lambda\}$ be an indexed family of topological spaces, and for each $\alpha\in\Lambda$ let $f_\alpha:X\to X_\alpha$ be a function. Furthermore, let $\mathscr{T}$ be the weak topology on X induced by $\{f_\alpha:\alpha\in\Lambda\}$. Then $\mathscr{L}=\{f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha):\alpha\in\Lambda; U_\alpha\in\mathscr{T}_\alpha\}$ is a subbasis for $\mathscr{T}$.

I have tried this: Since $f_\alpha$ is continuous therefore $f_\alpha^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is open then, intersections of elements of $\mathscr{L}$ are open. Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the set of all of those finite intersections then if $B_1,B_2\in\mathscr{B}$ and $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, ($x\in X$), then there exist $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B$ and $B\subseteq B_1\cap B_2$. I need to prove that $X=\cup\{B:B\in\mathscr{B}\}$.

- First I would like to know some important properties of a weak topology.
- And of course I would like to see a proof of this theorem please.

Answer (score 9):

It looks to me as if what you are calling "weak topology" in your question is commonly referred to as [initial topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology).

As for the question why the set you describe is a subbase for the weak topology on $X$: I am not sure there is anything to show. That it is a subbase means that it generates the (weak) topology that is, that the weak topology is the smallest topology containing $\mathscr L$ as a subset. But if every map $f_\alpha$ is to be continuous, the topology must contain at least all sets in $\mathscr L$. But the weak topology is defined to be the smallest topology such that all $f_\alpha$ are continuous. Hence they have to be equal.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. When you say "they have to be equal" who do you mean?

Comment: @FernandoValle I mean the weak topology and the topology generated by $\mathscr L$.

Comment: Since the weak topology contains at least all sets in $\mathscr{L}$, it must contain the finite intersections of $\mathscr{L}$ and the unions of those intersections?

Comment: @Fernando: Certainly: by definition a topology is closed under taking finite intersections and arbitrary unions.

Comment: In general topology *weak topology* is synonymous with *initial topology* (and the term that I first learned).

Comment: @FernandoValle What Brian said. Sorry for  the late reply.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I thought of the weak topology as what one calls the initial topology if one considers the topology induced by $X^\ast$. Now I realise that that was probably a misconception. I will edit my answer.

Comment: That’s the usage in the topological vector space setting, but the term is also used in general topology. The terms *initial topology* and *final topology* weren’t in common use when I learned my topology; I suspect that they come from category theory, or at least from people with a category-theoretic background.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, I assumed the same about the category-theoretic origin of the terms.

Comment: I understand that both topologies, the topology generated by $\mathscr{L}$ and the weak topology, contains $\mathscr{L}$, but I don´t understand why they are the same. Could $\mathscr{L}$ generate a topology finer than the weak topology?

Comment: @FernandoValle No, that's not possible. The second paragraph in my answer is trying to explain why it's not possible. The topology "generated by $\mathscr L$" is the smallest topology containing all sets in $\mathscr L$.

Comment: Good! finally I understanding, I thank both for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a set $X$ with maps $f_\alpha: X \rightarrow X_\alpha$, where $X_\alpha$ are topological spaces, the weak topology is the smallest topology on $X$ such that the $f_\alpha$ are continuous (explicitly, one can take it to be the intersection of all topologies on $X$ for which $f_\alpha$ are continuous).

To prove your claim, just show that $\mathcal{L}$ have to be open in any topology for which $f_\alpha$ are continuous.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer, I know that all the elements of $\mathscr{L}$ are open, that is a result of the continuity of $f_\alpha$